# How can I move my AWS Lightsail Account to a different hosting provider?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I been trying to figure out how can I migrate my site from AWS-Lightsail to another hosting provider.   Normally I would just download all the files from my file directory then upload them to the new hosting provider but I can't even access my files through AWS Lightsail.

Can someone please help me figure out how to download the contents of my WordPress site/database so I can switch hosting providers?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended method to upload / download files to / from Amazon Lightsail is using SFTP. There are several SSH based file browsers. I work with Windows so I use [Bitvise](https://www.bitvise.com/). From the Amazon Lightsail Console download your SSH Keypair.

Follow the documentation for your SSH / SFTP client and setup the SSH Keypair and then connect to your instance. You can then upload / download files.

Answer (score 0):

Use a WordPress backup and restore program such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/ . The free version does perfect backup and restores from one host to another. Maybe get a technician to help you if you don't feel comfortable with it. This seems to be a ServerFault issue though?